# Multiple wordpress sites at one host

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have problems with one of my Wordpress sites at my host.

```
Today I installed "Traffic Stats Widget" - plugin and I followed their instructions for installation. So , I did this: 

Create a robots.php file on the root directory of your blog: ie public_html/your-blog/ Paste the following code without // in it:
# #
Open .htaccess file in the same directory and paste this in it:
RewriteRule robots.txt robots.php

Make sure you have the 'RewriteEngine On' clause in place...

Make sure you have a robots.txt file, even an empty one, on the root directory
```

After that I was unable to access all of my subpages.

This is link of my website:

http://idealpvc-dev.com/websites/camel/

And if you try to access some of subpages you will get error 404.

I don't know why, because I restored my .htaccess file but still it doesn't work.

Also I made comparison with others .htaccess file on other wordpress sites but there isn't any differences except folder names.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Also, above is content of my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /websites/camel/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /websites/camel/index.php [L]

</IfModule>



# END WordPress
```

Sites is located at /public_html/websites/camel

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this as a RewrieBase in your htaccess file

```
RewriteBase http://idealpvc-dev.com/websites/camel/
```

Instead of this

```
RewriteBase /websites/camel/
```

And make your [wordpress permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) Default From Wordpress Admin panel > Settings >> Permalink >>> Default